# SKMapViewHolder crashes on Nexus 5

Tags: skmaps

After adding the libraries to the project and instantiating everything according to the getting started guide (http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#) and the demo (http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download) I am running into some strange problems.

After adding the SKMapViewHolder to an activity, the app crashes and logcat returns the following:

```
06-05 14:22:48.388    1976-2013/com.x.app E/Adreno-ES11﹕ <qglDrvAPI_glDeleteTextures:371>: GL_INVALID_VALUE
06-05 14:22:48.388    1976-2013/com.x.app A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1), thread 2013 (Thread-885)
```

This is happening on a USB Nexus 5 and N5 emulator. On running it with an N7 (2012) emulator it's just returning the second *libc* error.

Comment: Caused by an incorrect path to the map creator file. I accidentally put my assets in /assets instead of /app/src/main/assets.